# Alignment is not correct

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, salesforce-id

I have 6 attachment in a VF page. But the alignment is not right it i coming like this [image]

You can see the apex:inputfile in red. I am not able to understand why this is not coming right. Can anybody guide me what i am doing wrong. My VF page code is

```
<!--Receipt Upload-->
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" title="Expense Receipt">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput" /> 
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" id="fileInput"
          filename="{!attachment.name}" dir="RTL" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput1" />
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment1.body}" id="fileInput1"
          filename="{!attachment1.name}" dir="RTL1" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput2" />
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment2.body}" id="fileInput2"
          filename="{!attachment2.name}" dir="RTL2" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput3" />
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment3.body}" id="fileInput3"
          filename="{!attachment3.name}" dir="RTL3" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput4" />
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment4.body}" id="fileInput4"
          filename="{!attachment4.name}" dir="RTL4" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="" for="fileInput5" />
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment5.body}" id="fileInput5"
          filename="{!attachment5.name}" dir="RTL5" accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.docx" size="50" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Looks odd, have you tried 'Inspect(ing) Element' using Chrome to see what's going on with the HTML?  This works fine in my browser...

Comment: If You have no other option i would suggest using Tr and Td html tags .But this code looks fine for me

Comment: Remove the Dir attribute from the input field component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a case of some delicious copypasta!

The *dir* attribute only accepts two values.  "LTR" and "RTL".  "LTR" is the default.  Only your first inputFile has a valid value for the *dir* attribute, so all the others end up being the default "LTR" while the first is "RTL".

Just remove the dir attribute from all of em.